Legendre's Irrationality Condition for Generalized Continued Fractions
This MathOverflow post cites that Legendre allegedly showed that given $a_{i}\in\mathbb{Z}\setminus\left\{0\right\}, b_{i}\in\mathbb{Z}$,
$$\cfrac{a_1}{b_1 + \cfrac{a_2}{b_2 + \cfrac{a_3}{b_3 + \cdots}}}$$
is irrational if $|a_i|<|b_i|$, for any sufficiently large $i$. Can anyone prove this or provide a reference?

The reference to Legendre's proof is: A. M. Legendre, Essai sur la théorie des nombres, (1798). For a modern discussion, see On a Theorem of Legendre in the theory of continued fractions (1994).
